# [Web Scrapping][python] ¿Cómo puedo extraer la URL de cada pagina junto con los otros datos extraídos?

Tags: python, web, scrapy

Estoy ensayando scrapy, un módulo de python para copiar info de paginas web.

A través de Xpaths puedo seleccionar el contenido html que quiero conservar de cada pagina. Tengo 'spiders' que van link por link copiando la informacion que yo quiero.

Sin embargo no tengo idea como puedo hacer para copiar informacion que esta fuera del contenido html, como le url de la pagina, que me gustaria tener tabulada con los demas datos.

Tengo entendido que puedo identificar la url como "HTTP HOST", pero no se cómo aqui. Por ejemplo, toda la informacion que obtengo la escribo asi:

```
item['titulo'] = response.xpath('').extract_first()
```

Como puedo guardarme la URL también?

PD: Otra pregunta que me surgió es acerca del contenido web que se genera luego de una acción. Por ejemplo, una pagina tiene oculta el numero de telefono, y cuando haces click se muestra. ¿Como puedo identificar ese contenido que aparece luego de hacer click?

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre la primera pregunta, el parámetro `response` que recibe tu función, en la que tienes el objeto HTML de la respuesta sobre el que puedes usar `xpath`, también tiene un atributo llamado `url` que te informa de la URL de la que descargó esa respuesta, así que supongo que puedes hacer:

```
item["url"] = response.url
```

La segunda pregunta es mucho más complicada. Dependiendo de cómo esté implementada la web, es posible que el campo oculto lo esté sólo mediante estilos CSS, en cuyo caso la información que buscabas ya estaba en el HTML aunque no estuviera visible y por tanto podrías extraerla con `xpath` como cualquier otra, o pudiera ser que esa información no existiera aún en el momento de descargarse la página y que fuera creada a posteriori desde un código JavaScript ejecutado en respuesta a la pulsación del usuario.

Si es la segunda forma, desde Python no tienes forma de acceder a ese dato, pues sería necesario antes ejecutar el javascript de la página, cosa que python no puede hacer. No obstante es posible usar scrapy para "manejar por control remoto" (por así decir) un navegador real. Dejar que el navegador descargue la página, simular la pulsación del usuario, y pedirle al navegador el HTML resultante.

El software necesario para "teledirigir" el navegador se llama Selenium y aquí tienes algún ejemplo de cómo integrarlo con Scrapy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia.

No he logrado obtenerla todavia junto con todos los demás datos. En la consola veo que el item "url" se carga bien, sin embargo no me aparece en la planilla csv al final, la única diferencia que veo con los otros items que extraigo es que los demas tienen ".extract()" al final. Trate de agregarlo asi:

item["url"] = response.url.extract()

Pero esto me da un error.